# HttpWebResponse: The operation has timed out

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

Im setting up a project on a new dev machine. (Win7, vs2k12)
The code works fine on the production machine.
This code gives me "The operation has timed out".

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = TimeoutMilliSeconds;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.UserAgent = "X";                
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The url works fine when I call it from the browser.
I know which ports are open for incoming traffic.
Im using IIS express.
How do I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: have you a proxy on your browser?

Comment: I have an adress and port already filled in, but the checkbox "Use a proxy for your lan" is not checked.

Comment: I've only one suggestion.. use Fiddler to monitoring both request (Browser / Code) and check the difference...

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ReadWriteTimeout` property.For details see a link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout.aspx

```
request.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000; //Increase Time as your requirement.
```

Comment: It seems to work now. Still using 100000. 
Why do I need this when the production env doesnt?

Comment: production env handle itself but dev machine doesn't so u must define yourself. dev machine has different settings.

Comment: It seems to go up & down. Yesterday was ok, now I get the timeout again. What is your guess?